# How to Create Header on j2me(java) screen

Tags: java-me, lcdui, midp-2.0

I want to create a Header on my j2me lcdui list Screen. How can I create it? When I click on my lcdui list screen, I will navigate to lcdui form screen, that time header will  has to be same.

How can I create? I have used this class `com.nokia.mid.ui.DirectUtils` but failed.

Comment: When you say Header do you mean a text right below the screen title? Have you tried to use javax.microedition.lcdui.Ticker?

Comment: no,for advertisement to show on the screen header?

Comment: set both screens same title or same ticker using `Displayable.setTitle` or `Displayable.setTicker` methods, respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert an advertisement Image with empty String using [List.insert](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.microedition.lcdui.Image%29).

```
list.insert(0, "", adImage);
```

But this image might be scrolled up if you have enough items in the list. If you need an advertisement image fixed under the title you might consider using LWUIT instead of LCDUI.